# Seeing heights in Landsat 8

Tags: elevation, landsat-8, slope, landsat-7

I have downloaded some DEM from Landsat 8 from usgs website.
when I opened the compressed file I saw some Tiff files and two text files.
I opened the txt file using ArcGIS 10.7 and it contains many other files such as Panchromatic, Water, Thermal,Landcover and etc as following:

[image]

I opened Panchromatic bcoz I have heard the Horizontal accuracy is 15 meter.
I want to report slope and elevation of some certain points.
but something is odd. when I read the elevation, the elevation is not correct I think these are in terms of binary values!

[image]

plus I downloaded this area from Landsat 7 as following:

[image]

the first one is Landsat 7 and the second one is Landsat 8.

*how should I convert Landsat 8 elevations?

*which layers in Landsat 8 I should use to report elevations and slope? (bcoz it contains many Tiff files) is it better than SRTM 1 arc-second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panchromatic is black and white imagery, not a DEM. The file you downloaded is not a DEM.

Try this:
1.) USGS Earth Explorer-Home
2.) Set your study area (Address/County/City/etc.)
3.) On the same page, click on "Data Sets"
4.) Click on the tab for "Digitial Elevation"
5.) Click on the subtab for "SRTM Void Filled" *My favorite DEM
6.) Download and add to your map.

Note: The values will be in meters.

Comment: Thank you, I have downloaded SRTM 1 arc-second from Global Mapper software, is it SRTM Void Filled? I have checked this link: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SRTM it says SRTM V3 is void filled.

Comment: It should say if it is void filled. Void filled just means that any pixels that didn't have a value would be given one by an algorithm. It saves a step from having to do it with GIS. Void filled is important if you are working with hydrology/stream flow.